# Prepopulating a drop-down select box that references another entity

Tags: entities, forms

I have a node create form for content type "space" so that the URL looks like https://.../node/add/space.

In this page, there is a form with a drop-down select that corresponds to an entity reference field type to a "floor" content type.

I would like that value to be pre-populated from a URL parameter or similar and I was trying with the Entity Reference module. I added *[current-page:query:floor]* in the Entity Prepopulate value for the floor field and then tried to pass that parameter via URL as https://.../node/add/space?floor=floor 1.

That does not pre-populate the select box as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I needed to query the ID and not the actual value. Like
"https://.../node/add/space?floor=1" or "https://.../node/add/space?floor=floor 2"